# Database table design for situation dependent data

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

Let's say you have a table that will contain data that is very situation dependent.

An example would be a collection of games where the player makes a selection to win. This selection should be stored, but the games are different and so a selection in one game doesn't really fit the selection in another game.

In general, is it better to make the table broad enough to handle all the cases and leave some (but different) parts unused for every entry, or should I make a special table for every case?

Or is there some other technique that would be better?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, if I understand you right, it seems you desire an m:n-relation which would require 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE game
    (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    game nchar(x)
    )

CREATE TABLE solution
    (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    solution nchar(x)
    )

CREATE TABLE game_solution
    (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    id_game int NULL REFERENCES game( id),
    id_solution int NULL REFERENCES solution( id)
    )
```

Comment: My question would then be: what if the solutions to the different games don't necessarily fit in an nchar? Maybe one game is multiple choice, one is multiple answer, one has two answers etc.

Comment: @Lars: There are various ways:
a)  Since it seems the different solutions are unstructured, you are dependent
    on the size of the data types your RDBMS offers;
b)  an alternative would be to save the solutions in files and store the links
    to the files in the table [solution].
c)  You could also mix it, e. g. store shorter solutions inside the table
    [solution] and longer solutions in files.
However, in MS SQL VARBINARY(MAX) provides 2^31 - 1 bytes, that's almost
2 GiB. I hardly can imagine a game's solution requiring more storage!
Could you share how you solved the problem meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way to general, so the short answer is: It depends! The longer one is: The "broad" table is a easy solution if you have only a few games which do not differ very much. There are cases where I would go for that solution, but in general not.

My advise would be: Ask yourself, what's common for all selections/choices. That data should go to a general table. The data special to a certain game should go to a separated related table per game.

Don't know how your background as a programmer is. But if your familiar with OO programming, just google for strategies how to map class hierarchies to SQL databases.

Comment: So following my contrived example, I should make an "answer" table, with a "type_id" column. Then, JOIN an appropriate table e.g. "answer_type_a" with "answer"?

Comment: Yes, for example. But there are 1001 options and it really depends on your exact data. If the answer table has only the type_id column, it makes not much sense of course. Depending on your query requirements and your database engine, you might also use xml or json columns. Postgresqls hstore might also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

@Lars: I just reread your question.

To keep it short:

1. If you need *maximum performance*, keep it completely structured, even if you have to create many new tables.
2. If you need *flexibility*, e. g. storing the results of future games which result-structure you don't know yet, without considering performance, store binary values or links to files containing the solutions.
3. If you need *flexibility* AND *better performance* AND already know the structures of the *most common solution-types*, store these in structured tables and all other, unpredictable (future) solutions, as binary or links to files.
4. If you want to keep it easy, use points 1 or 2, as 3 adds a lot of complexity to your program.

I hope this is the proper answer. I'm curious, if anybody has a better suggestion!